# ¿Como puedo comparar si una fecha es menor a la fecha actual del servidor?

Tags: php, ajax

como puedo comparar fechas una ingresada en la base de datos con la fecha actual del servidor y saber si la fecha que esta en la base de datos es menor a la actual o fecha actual del servidor para realizar la acción siguiente. algo asi es lo que quiero hacer

```
"select * from publi where carrerae LIKE '%Informatica%' AND fecha (es menor a) date(y-m-d) ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Comment: Detalla un poco más tu pregunta por favor. No se entiende bien qué quieres decir; agrega un caso de uso como ejemplo y el código que llevas hasta el momento. Mientras editas tu pregunta, te invito a [hacer un recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio y a consultar la guía [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Espero y ya me explique mejor

Comment: tiene que ser en PHP y Ajax pero tu ejemplo es en SQL. No se entiende en qué quieres hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a aventurar una respuesta. **En MySQL**, Para obtener los registros cuya fecha sea menor a la fecha actual del sistema, se usa la función `CURDATE`.

Si tu campo `fecha` es realmente una fecha o al menos puede interpretarse como tal, entonces los registros que quieres obtener salen de:

```
SELECT * 
FROM publi 
WHERE carrerae LIKE '%Informatica%' 
AND fecha < CURDATE() 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Prueba con esto, funciona para mi**

```
    <?php
    $datetime1 = date_create(date('Y-m-d')); //fecha actual  
    $datetime2 = date_create($row['FechaDB']); //fecha de db  
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2,false);  
    $dias = intval($interval->format('%R%a'));  

    if ($dias < 0) {
        echo "Mayor 1";
    }else if ($dias == 0) {
        echo "iguales";
    }else if ($dias > 0) {
        echo "Mayor 2";
    }
    ?>
```